# Need explanation of a query

Tags: sql

```
WHERE y.continent=x.continent
```

and the original query is

```
SELECT continent, name, population 
FROM world x   
WHERE population >= ALL (SELECT population 
                         FROM world y 
                         WHERE y.continent = x.continent           
                         AND population > 0)
```

Comment: What do you think is going on here? Please explain your thought process and maybe we can point the problems in it.

Comment: This query has the effect of a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query (mostly), in that it finds the most-populous countries (?) on each continent.  Depending on your RDBMS, there are more efficient ways to write this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALL (SELECT population FROM world y WHERE y.continent=x.continent AND population>0)
```

This part of the query returns a set of population based on continent and where the population is greater than zero.

`y.continent=x.continent` is a join on table `world`